# Identificar casos com várias condições em várias colunas no R

Tags: r, condição

Eu possuo um dataframe com 20 alunos e preciso identificar os alunos que frequentaram a etapa 43 por dois anos ou mais.

```
aluno <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20)
etapa_2012 <- c(42, 43, 44, 43, 42, 43, 44, 45, 42, 43, 44, 45, 42, 43, 44, 44, 42, 43, 44, 45)
etapa_2013 <- c(43, 44, 45, 43, 43, 44, 45, 45, 43, 43, 45, 45, 43, 44, 45, 44, 43, 44, 45, 45)
etapa_2014 <- c(44, 45, 45, 43, 44, 45, 45, 45, 44, 43, 45, 45, 44, 45, 45, 45, 44, 45, 45, 45)
etapa_2015 <- c(45, 45, 45, 44, 45, 45, 45, 44, 43, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 44, 43, 45, 45, NA)
fluxo<-data.frame(aluno, etapa_2012, etapa_2013, etapa_2014, etapa_2015)
```

Mas só consigo acrescentar nova coluna identificando os alunos que fizeram a etapa 43.

```
fluxo$dois_ou_mais <-ifelse(fluxo$etapa_2012==43|fluxo$etapa_2013==43|fluxo$etapa_2014==43|fluxo$etapa_2015==43, 1, 0)
fluxo
```

Assim tenho o resultado[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu gostaria de chegar ao resultado em que somente os alunos 4, 9, 10 e 17 fossem marcados na coluna dois_ou_mais, já que possuem a etapa 43 em mais de um ano, conforme imagem abaixo.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Utilize o comando

```
fluxo[, 2:5]==43
```

Assim, cada posição das colunas de 2 a 5 será testada para verificar se são iguais a 43. Assim, será criado um objeto com `TRUE` e `FALSE`.

```
head(fluxo[, 2:5]==43)
     etapa_2012 etapa_2013 etapa_2014 etapa_2015
[1,]      FALSE       TRUE      FALSE      FALSE
[2,]       TRUE      FALSE      FALSE      FALSE
[3,]      FALSE      FALSE      FALSE      FALSE
[4,]       TRUE       TRUE       TRUE      FALSE
[5,]      FALSE       TRUE      FALSE      FALSE
[6,]       TRUE      FALSE      FALSE      FALSE
```

Para o `R`, `TRUE` tem valor 1 e `FALSE` tem valor 0. Assim, basta somar o número de `TRUE` em cada linha:

```
apply(head(fluxo[, 2:5]==43), 1, sum)
[1] 1 1 0 3 1 1
```

Para saber quem cursou mais de uma vez, sem se preocupar com o número de vezes que a pessoa cursou, utilize o comando abaixo:

```
as.numeric(apply(head(fluxo[, 2:5]==43), 1, sum)>1)
[1] 0 0 0 1 0 0
```

Remova os `head` da solução que passei e tudo vai se encaixar para resolver o teu problema com o tamanho original.

Comment: Já agora, porque não `as.integer`?

Comment: Posso estar enganado, mas creio que não há diferença prática entre `as.integer` e `as.numeric` no `R` caso os valores numéricos sejam utilizados dentro do próprio `R`. Se eu precisasse passar o resultado deste comando para um programa em C, faria diferença transformar os dados em inteiro ou ponto flutuante. Dentro do `R` acho que tanto faz usar uma função ou a outra.

Answer (score 3):

usando a função `rowSums` para obter a tabela como você pediu

```
fluxo$dois_ou_mais <- as.numeric(rowSums(fluxo[,-1] == 43, na.rm = TRUE) > 1)
```

Mas se você estiver interessado em obter apenas os alunos, sem modificar a tabela original. Eu prefiro usar `tidyr` e `dplyr`

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
fluxo %>% gather(key = ano, value = etapa, -aluno) %>% 
          filter(etapa == 43) %>% group_by(aluno) %>% 
          summarise( N = n()) %>% filter(N > 1)
```